# Hexadecimal to Binary program - Python

Tags: python

I am doing an exam paper for revision. It's not a particular question I want help with, but I am unsure to why the program is outputting incorrectly when certain data is entered.

```
def Binary(Hex):
    Result = ''
    ErrorFound = False
    BinaryEquivalent = ''
    EmptyInput=""
    for ThisHexDigit in Hex:
        if ThisHexDigit in ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','A','B','C','D','E','F']:
            if ThisHexDigit == '0': BinaryEquivalent = '0'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '1': BinaryEquivalent = '1'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '2': BinaryEquivalent = '2'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '3': BinaryEquivalent = '3'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '4': BinaryEquivalent = '4'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '5': BinaryEquivalent = '5'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '6': BinaryEquivalent = '6'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '7': BinaryEquivalent = '7'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '8': BinaryEquivalent = '8'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '9': BinaryEquivalent = '9'
            elif ThisHexDigit == 'A': BinaryEquivalent = '10'
            elif ThisHexDigit == 'B': BinaryEquivalent = '11'
            elif ThisHexDigit == 'C': BinaryEquivalent = '12'
            elif ThisHexDigit == 'D': BinaryEquivalent = '13'
            elif ThisHexDigit == 'E': BinaryEquivalent = '14'
            elif ThisHexDigit == 'F': BinaryEquivalent = '15'
            Result = Result + BinaryEquivalent
        elif ErrorFound == True:
            print('You have made a mistake')
        elif Hex==EmptyInput:
            print('Empty input, try again.')

    return Result
```

Yes, I know this is an over-complicated piece of code but it is in the exam paper so I have to use it. It came like that, except that all the BinaryEquivalent strings were `BinaryEquivalent = ''` instead of having numbers inside.

The problem is when I enter two characters when the program is displaying. For example, entering "BBB" will output 11, as will 'BBBBBB'.

Comment: "it is in the exam paper"? Everything about this code is wrongly conceived.

Comment: How about `try: BinaryEquivalent=str(int(ThisHexDigit, 16)) catch ValueError: print "You have made a mistake."` or something similar? (you have to add newlines but a comment cannot handle code formatting properly). Your code is ugly on so many frontiers that I suggest a rewrite.

Comment: Wow, that's some really ugly code!  Not related to your question, but its not good to name variables starting with uppercase, e.g. `Result` would be better as `result`.  See [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: I "fixed" the indentation in the code, because I thought you just had problems posting it, but it seems likely that it was actually the problem you were having, based on the first couple of responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put `return` statement out of the `for` cycle.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement is inside the `for` loop and therefore only one iteration is done, it should be:

```
for ThisHexDigit in Hex:
    #code

return result
```

and not:

```
for ThisHexDigit in Hex:
    #code
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is good only if your hex number is single hex digit. If you want to convert longer numbers you will have to do some corrections.

1. `Result` can be simple int, start it with 0
2. all BinaryEquivalent should be ints so use `BinaryEquivalent = 0`
3. in for loop you must increase your result, use: `Result = 16 * Result + BinaryEquivalent`